# Hive - Column Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

Tags: hadoop, hive, subquery

I need to create a table in Hive that have multiple sub-queries. The query is:

```
CREATE TABLE table AS
select dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY Client) AS Client,
       A.STORE,
       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(A.DATE_Client , 'yyyy-MM-dd')) AS Date_Client,
      year(A.DATE_Client) as YEAR_Client,
       (INT((MONTH(A.DATE_Client)-1)/3)+1) as QUARTER_Client,
       MONTH(A.DATE_Client) as MONTH_Client,
       weekofyear(A.DATE_Client) as WEEK_Client,
       DAY(A.DATE_Client) as DAY_Client,
       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(A.DATE_Client , 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'u') as WeekDay,
       b.Last_Visit,
       A.transaction_value/A.transaction_Quantity AS PRODUCT_VALUE
from (select e.*,
            tb1.seqnum
      from (SELECT Distinct d.STORE as STORE_rank,DENSE_RANK() over (order by d.STORE, RAND()) as seqnum from staging_area d) tb1
      join staging_area e
      on tb1.STORE_rank = e.STORE
     ) A
JOIN (SELECT Client, MAX(DATE_Client) AS Last_Visit
            FROM LAST_VISIT
            GROUP BY Client) B
ON A.Client = B.Client
where seqnum < 41 and Date_Client >= '2013-01-01' and Date_Client <= '2013-30';
```

However, when I try to run this I'm getting the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Column client Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries
```

Anyone knows how can I solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: The error message is quite straightforward: in clause `OVER (ORDER BY Client)` do you mean `A.Client` or `B.Client`? **You** know that they are equivalent **in this context**, because of the equi-join, but the Hive compiler is not subtile enough to "know" that.

Comment: That's correct :D Could you put in answers to close the thread? Many thanks!